# Trying to return an json array but am getting JSON Parse error

Tags: php, jquery, json

To anyone who can help, I am trying to return an array and am getting
a JSON parse error yet when I run it through http://jsonlint.com it 
returns fine. Has anybody got some suggestions as I have been at this for
quite a while and getting nowhere. Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
     $.ajax({  
      url: 'images/retrieve_images.php',    
      data: 'page_id='+ encodeURIComponent(page_id),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {

      var results = $.parseJSON(data);

        $.each(results, function(i, result) {

        $("<img width='50px' height='auto' src='../article_images/"+result.image_name+"'/>").appendTo("#image_list");
        $("<p>"+result.original_image_name+"</p>").appendTo('#image_list');

        if (result.image_layout == "normal") {
        $("<p><input type='checkbox' name='normal' id='element_id' class='background_input element_id' value='normal' checked> Normal</p>").appendTo('#image_list');
        $("<p><input type='checkbox' name='extended' id='element_id' class='background_input element_id' value='extended'> Extended</p>").appendTo('#image_list');
        $("<p><input type='checkbox' name='revolving' id='element_id' class='background_input element_id' value='revolving'> Revolving</p>").appendTo('#image_list');       
        }
    });
    }
    });
```

Php retrieve below:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM elements WHERE page_id = '$page_id'");

$rows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

JSON Output below:

[["634","1","1","1","checked","image",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"653364494e41b2baeb9f3bd8dd88380f.png","test image.jpg","extended","grayscale",null,"solid","0","0","0","000000","0","000000","0","solid","1","0",null,"0","0","0","0","000000","150","100","388","554","-100",null,"unchecked","2016-03-17 18:31:24"],["642","1","1","1","checked","image",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"b320a437bcd56282ca12c06750079ad1.png","test image2.jpg","normal","rgb",null,"solid","0","0","0","000000","0","000000","0","solid","1","0",null,"0","0","0","0","000000","55","184","321","525","",null,"unchecked","2016-03-17 18:54:40"]]

Comment: Can you share the JSON output?

Comment: It would be a LOT easier to help you debug JSON if you showed us the JSON.

Comment: Sorry, have added it to the question. Thanks

Comment: `data` is **already an object** (thanks to `dataType: 'json'`). You don't need to *re-parse* it.

Comment: @Phil: I think you mean `data` is already an array / object. JSON always needs to be parsed to native data structures.

Comment: Ok, I have removed the parseJSON but I am now getting "undefined" errors, how do I assign the variable for example element_type? If I alert  the data it returns the JSON ok. Thanks for your help so far.